# Connection Error When Adding Any New Package With Poetry

Tags: python, connection, wsl-2, python-poetry

Whenever I try to add a new package with poetry (using `poetry add <package_name>`), I get the following connection error:

```
 ConnectionError

  ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/requests/adapters.py:498 in send
      494│                     low_conn.close()
      495│                     raise
      496│ 
      497│         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
    → 498│             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
      499│ 
      500│         except MaxRetryError as e:
      501│             if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
      502│                 # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
```

Things I have already tried:

- Different packages (e.g.: rsa, jupyter). This happens with some of PyPi's most popular ones, as well.
- Running the command in debugging mode, which didn't yield anything of use other than this error.
- Installing without poetry, via pip (which worked).
- Trying different IDEs (Pycharm's terminal & Jupyter). This happened with both.

Environment: I am using poetry version 1.1.12, with WSL-2.

Comment: FYI, the solution here did not help (and also, it is supposedly merged into the latest poetry version): https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3219